# Getting infinite loop on useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Trying to build a tooltip component. When the tooltip moves away from the viewport need to switch the tooltip position that is working fine . But when the tooltip is away from the viewport useEffect running infinitely. cant able to find the root cause.

Adding sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/dbpkr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a dependency array

```
useEffect(() => {;
    let intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries) {
      if (!entries[0].isIntersecting) {
        setMoveBottom(moveBottom => !moveBottom);
      }
    });

    if (refElement) intersectionObserver.observe(refElement);

    return () => {
      if (refElement) intersectionObserver.unobserve(refElement);
    };
  }, [setMoveBottom, refElement]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah because you are not passing dependency for useEffect hook.

So add either empty array or pass any dependencies by end of the useEffect

Eg:

```
 useEffect(() => {


}, [])
```

for more info read this [enter link description here](https://medium.com/better-programming/understanding-the-useeffect-dependency-array-2913da504c44)

Comment: added dependency array but issue still exists

Comment: could you please check any unnecessary api calls going on in network tab, If there write logic based on page/component render